# Is there any websocket plugin for IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, plugins, websocket

Is there any plugin for IE, with I can use Websockets in IE 7-8-9?
I haven't found any :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One of the fallbacks used by socket.io is the flash one: [gimite/web-socket-js](https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js).

It uses flash to establish a socket connection. Because of this you can get WebSocket support on pretty much any legacy platform, since they all have flash.

Answer (score 2):

There is no native WS support until Internet Explorer 10. However, you might consider using a JavaScript library such as Socket.IO, which can be used for cross-browser WebSockets support.

Comment: One of the fallbacks used by socket.io is the flash one: https://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js

Comment: @igorw - Your comment correctly answers this question. web-socket.js provides a native WebSocket interface within the web page runtime. Please post your comment as an answer and I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a client socket script as said by @igorw which currently works in IE 9 (hopefully, IE 8 also) and other modern browsers!! (Checked in Chrome Version 33 and Firefox 27)

https://github.com/sk8terboi87/labs/tree/sockets

(Btw: server socket is done using php http://socketo.me)

(For explanation: http://codelikeapoem.com/2014/03/php-socket-programming-part-ii.html)