# Socket.io, cluster, express and sync events

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, cluster-computing

I have a big problem sice 1 week. I try to convert my node.JS project actually run on single core to multi core with cluster.

With websockets, at this moment, i have no problems for events but, for xhr-polling or jsonp-polling, i have big problems with socket.io on cluster mode.

this is my server configuration :

00-generic.js

```
'use strict';

var http            = require('http'),
    os              = require('os'),
    cluster         = require('cluster');

module.exports = function(done) {
    var app = this.express,
        port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
        address = '0.0.0.0';

    if(this.env == 'test'){
        port = 3030;
    }

    var self = this;
    var size = os.cpus().length;

    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        console.info('Creating HTTP server cluster with %d workers', size);

        for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            console.log('spawning worker process %d', (i + 1));
            cluster.fork();
        }

        cluster.on('fork', function(worker) {
            console.log('worker %s spawned', worker.id);
        });
        cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
            console.log('worker %s online', worker.id);
        });
        cluster.on('listening', function(worker, addr) {
            console.log('worker %s listening on %s:%d', worker.id, addr.address, addr.port);
        });
        cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
            console.log('worker %s disconnected', worker.id);
        });
        cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
            console.log('worker %s died (%s)', worker.id, signal || code);
            if (!worker.suicide) {
                console.log('restarting worker');
                cluster.fork();
            }
        });
    } else {
        http.createServer(app).listen(port, address, function() {
            var addr = this.address();
            console.log('listening on %s:%d', addr.address, addr.port);
            self.server = this;
            done();
        });
    }
};
```

03-socket.io.js

```
"use strict";
var _               = require('underscore'),
    socketio        = require('socket.io'),
    locomotive      = require('locomotive'),
    RedisStore      = require("socket.io/lib/stores/redis"),
    redis           = require("socket.io/node_modules/redis"),
    v1              = require(__dirname + '/../app/socket.io/v1'),
    sockets         = require(__dirname + '/../../app/socket/socket'),
    config          = require(__dirname + '/../app/global'),
    cluster         = require('cluster');

module.exports = function () {
    if (!cluster.isMaster) {
        this.io = socketio.listen(this.server);

        var pub             = redis.createClient(),
            sub             = redis.createClient(),
            client          = redis.createClient();

        this.io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
        this.io.enable('browser client etag');          // apply etag caching logic based on version number
        this.io.enable('browser client gzip');          // gzip the file

        this.io.set("store", new RedisStore({
            redisPub        : pub,
            redisSub        : sub,
            redisClient     : client
        }));
        this.io.set('log level', 2);
        this.io.set('transports', [
            'websocket',
            'jsonp-polling'
        ]);
        this.io.set('close timeout', 24*60*60);
        this.io.set('heartbeat timeout', 24*60*60);

        this.io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log('connected with ' + this.io.transports[socket.id].name);

            // partie v1 @deprecated
            v1.events(socket);

            // partie v1.1 refaite
            _.each(sockets['1.1'], function(Mod) {
                var mod = new Mod();
                mod.launch({
                    socket  : socket,
                    io      : this.io
                });
            }, this);

        }.bind(this));
    }
};
```

With polling, the client connects from time to time on a different process than that initiated listeners. Similarly, the communication server to the client with emit.

With a little searching, I found it necessary to pass by a store for socket.io to share the data connection. So I built RedisStore socket.io as shown in the documentation but even with that, I find myself with events not arriving safely and I still get this error message:

```
warn: client not handshaken client should reconnect
```

**EDIT**

Now, the warn error is not called. I change the redisStore to socket.io-clusterhub BUT now, events are not always called. Sometimes as if the polling request was captured by another worker than that which began the listeners and so it nothing happens. Here is the new configuration:

```
'use strict';

var http            = require('http'),
    locomotive      = require('locomotive'),
    os              = require('os'),
    cluster         = require('cluster'),
    config          = require(__dirname + '/../app/global'),
    _               = require('underscore'),
    socketio        = require('socket.io'),
    v1              = require(__dirname + '/../app/socket.io/v1'),
    sockets         = require(__dirname + '/../../app/socket/socket');

module.exports = function(done) {
    var app = this.express,
        port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
        address = '0.0.0.0';

    if(this.env == 'test'){
        port = 3030;
    }

    var self = this;
    var size = os.cpus().length;

    this.clusterStore = new (require('socket.io-clusterhub'));

    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
            console.log('spawning worker process %d', (i + 1));
            cluster.fork();
        }

        cluster.on('fork', function(worker) {
            console.log('worker %s spawned', worker.id);
        });
        cluster.on('online', function(worker) {
            console.log('worker %s online', worker.id);
        });
        cluster.on('listening', function(worker, addr) {
            console.log('worker %s listening on %s:%d', worker.id, addr.address, addr.port);
        });
        cluster.on('disconnect', function(worker) {
            console.log('worker %s disconnected', worker.id);
        });
        cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
            console.log('worker %s died (%s)', worker.id, signal || code);
            if (!worker.suicide) {
                console.log('restarting worker');
                cluster.fork();
            }
        });
    } else {
        var server = http.createServer(app);

        this.io = socketio.listen(server);

        this.io.configure(function() {
            this.io.enable('browser client minification');  // send minified client
            this.io.enable('browser client etag');          // apply etag caching logic based on version number
            this.io.enable('browser client gzip');          // gzip the file

            this.io.set('store', this.clusterStore);
            this.io.set('log level', 2);
            this.io.set('transports', [
                'websocket',
                'jsonp-polling'
            ]);
            //this.io.set('close timeout', 24*60*60);
            //this.io.set('heartbeat timeout', 24*60*60);
        }.bind(this));

        this.io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
            console.log('connected with ' + this.io.transports[socket.id].name);
            console.log('connected to worker: ' + cluster.worker.id);

            // partie v1 @deprecated
            v1.events(socket);

            // partie v1.1 refaite
            _.each(sockets['1.1'], function(Mod) {
                var mod = new Mod();
                mod.launch({
                    socket  : socket,
                    io      : this.io
                });
            }, this);

        }.bind(this));

        server.listen(port, address, function() {
            var addr = this.address();
            console.log('listening on %s:%d', addr.address, addr.port);
            self.server = this;
            done();
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Which socket.io version do you use. Could be a bug. But I would ask you to check this [issue](https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io/issues/996). Look for jwarkentin commented on Aug 22, 2013. There are helpful links in the post. In order to fix the problem you have to get the configuration right, apart from using the correct packages.

Comment: i use version 0.9.18 on client and server side

Answer (score 2):

From that source : http://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/

> If you plan to distribute the load of connections among different
>   processes or machines, you have to make sure that requests associated
>   with a particular session id connect to the process that originated
>   them.
>
> This is due to certain transports like XHR Polling or JSONP Polling
>   relying on firing several requests during the lifetime of the
>   “socket”.

To route connections to the same worker every time :

**sticky-session**

This is, in the socket.io documentation, the recommended way to route requests to the same worker every time.

https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session

> A simple performant way to use socket.io with a cluster.
>
> Socket.io is doing multiple requests to perform handshake and
>   establish connection with a client. With a cluster those requests may
>   arrive to different workers, which will break handshake protocol.

```
var sticky = require('sticky-sesion');

sticky(function() {
  // This code will be executed only in slave workers

  var http = require('http'),
      io = require('socket.io');

  var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    // ....
  });
  io.listen(server);

  return server;
}).listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('server started on 3000 port');
});
```

To pass messages between nodes :

**socket.io-redis**

This is, in socket.io documentation, the recommended way to share messages between workers.

https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-redis

> By running socket.io with the socket.io-redis adapter you can run
>   multiple socket.io instances in different processes or servers that
>   can all broadcast and emit events to and from each other.

socket.io-redis is used this way :

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

**Also**

I think you are not using socket.io v1.0.0. You might want to update your version in order to get more stability.

You can check their migration guide at http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/

Comment: i try this. On random api requests, i have request timeout with sticky -session. With socket.io 1.0.0 alone (without sticky-session) and the new redis storage, user reconnect all times and lost previous event handlers

Comment: Hi, can you gist your server config with sticky-sessions?

Comment: Can you also gist the socket file from require(__dirname + '/../../app/socket/socket');

Comment: Are you using [node.js core cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or [learn boost cluster module](https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster) ?

Comment: @ludo - please update your answer with a working version of sticky-session and express. I still have yet to find a working example: https://github.com/indutny/sticky-session/issues/7

Answer (score 2):

There is a step missing from the socket.io docs when using

```
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redis({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));
```

You need to tell the client that you want to use 'websockets' as the only form of transport or it will not work... so for the constructor on the client use

```
io.connect(yourURL , { transports : ['websocket']});
```

see my answer to a similar question here ( my answer might be more appropriate on this thread ):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30791006/4127352

Comment: for websocket, i agree with you. But my application must be compatible with ie9 and ie9 is not compatible with websocket

Comment: If you have access to all the machines using IE9 you could install plugins... there seems to have been some discussion around it( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8958072/is-there-any-websocket-plugin-for-ie )  I'm one of the fortunate ones who gets to ignore <IE10

Comment: I have no access to the ie9 machines. ie9 represent +/- 20% of our clients. We can't ignore them

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement sticky sessions via a proxy service - I do not recommend using the sticky-session node library, I had extremely wacky results with that

Comment: I agree with you. With sticky-session, I have several bugs

Answer (score 1):

The below code work for me, this is socket.io who created clusters, i set `config.clusterSticky` on `true` for activate compatibility clusters and socket.io

```
'use strict';

/*
 var cl = console.log;
 console.log = function(){
 console.trace();
 cl.apply(console,arguments);
 };
 */

var cluster = require('cluster'),
    config = require('./config/all'),
    deferred = require('q').defer(),
    express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    http = require('http'),
    sticky = require('socketio-sticky-session'),
    io = require('socket.io');

// Code to run if we're in the master process or if we are not in debug mode/ running tests

if ((cluster.isMaster) &&
    (process.execArgv.indexOf('--debug') < 0) &&
    (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') && (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development') &&
    (process.execArgv.indexOf('--singleProcess') < 0) &&
    (!config.clusterSticky)) {

    console.log('for real!');
    // Count the machine's CPUs
    var cpuCount = process.env.CPU_COUNT || require('os').cpus().length;

    // Create a worker for each CPU
    for (var i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
        console.log('forking ', i);
        cluster.fork();
    }

    // Listen for dying workers
    cluster.on('exit', function (worker) {
        // Replace the dead worker, we're not sentimental
        console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died :(');
        cluster.fork();
    });

// Code to run if we're in a worker process
} else {
    var port = config.http.port;
    var workerId = 0;
    if (!cluster.isMaster) {
        workerId = cluster.worker.id;
    }

    var server = http.createServer(app);
    io.listen(server);

    //TODO routes etc (core)

    server.on('listening', function () {
        console.log('Slave app started on port ' + port + ' (' + process.env.NODE_ENV + ') cluster.worker.id:', workerId);
    });

    if(config.clusterSticky && (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') && (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development')) {
        sticky(server).listen(port);
    } else {
        server.listen(port);
    }

    deferred.resolve(server);
}

module.exports = deferred.promise;
```

Comment: You used sticky session, in many cases, sticky session generate random issues and bugs and this is my case :(