# Any references of express with socket and reverse proxy http-proxy

Tags: node.js, socket.io, http-proxy

I am trying to create the following:

two instances of node.js application: app1, app2 running on ip1:3000, ip2:3000 respectively with socket communication enabled.

Now I have http-proxy server on 3838 used in reverse proxying app1 and app2.

But, i am having issues with making socket.io work in this case.

Any pointers pls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.io, cluster, express and sync events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886054/socket-io-cluster-express-and-sync-events)

Comment: Could you share some more details??